# SQL Inner Join for News Feed

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join

I am having some trouble with the Inner Join aspect of a statement.  I am trying to get all the "posts" from a users friends list on their news feed.  I'm trying to do so by getting all those posts where the user is the initiator_user_id and get all the posts from the friend_user_id then I want to get all the posts from initiator_user_id where the user's id is the friend_user_id.

Previously this works but it only gets the posts where the user is the initiator_user_id:

```
$wallsql= $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM activity f INNER JOIN wp_bp_friends n2 ON n2.friend_user_id=f.user_id WHERE n2.initiator_user_id=:userid ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 8');
```

Userid 24 can see userid 22's "posts" such as when 22's account was created and his status update.  What it NEEDS to do is let userid 22 see userid 24's updates as well.  Right now it's one sided.  I thought that the following would accomplish getting it to go both ways:

```
$wallsql= $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM activity f INNER JOIN wp_bp_friends n1 ON (n1.initiator_user_id=f.user_id) INNER JOIN wp_bp_friends n2 ON (n2.friend_user_id=f.user_id) WHERE (n1.friend_user_id=:userid) OR (n2.initiator_user_id=:userid) ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 8'); 
$wallsql->bindParam(':userid', $_SESSION['uid']);
$wallsql->execute();
```

Here is the tables and how they are set up.

```
wp_bp_friends table:

id     initiator_user_id     friend_user_id     is_confirmed     is_limited     date_created
11            24                    22                1               0          2013-12-11 11:17:26




Activity table:

ID     user_id                type                       component     filetype     group_id            content                     datetime
15        22             accountcreated                     NULL           NULL            0                NULL                2013-12-11 11:17:26
15        22                   status                       NULL           NULL            0           Hello World!          2013-12-11 11:17:26
15        24            accountcreated                      NULL           NULL             0               NULL                2013-12-11 11:17:26
15        24                   status                       NULL           NULL            0             Whats up            2013-12-11 11:17:26
```

Comment: Do separate queries for the two directions, and combine them with `UNION`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with UNION.  Could you show me in an answer?  I'm kind of on a time crunch with a client :-/  I'm never one to ask people to do it for me but I need help on this one quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   activity f 
       INNER JOIN wp_bp_friends n2 
               ON n2.friend_user_id = f.user_id 
WHERE  n2.initiator_user_id = :userid 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * 
FROM   activity f 
       INNER JOIN wp_bp_friends n2 
               ON n2.initiator_user_id = f.user_id 
WHERE  n2.friend_user_id = :userid 
ORDER  BY datetime DESC 
LIMIT  8
```